# How to get return value each state changed in another componentin React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React Component Passed a value, if Component Change state, How to return a new value from this component.
If ScrollDetecter state changed how to return value this component?

```
<ScrollDetector/> 

export default class ScrollDetector extends React.Component {
 //Most impotant function only metioned
handleScroll() {
const windowHeight = "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
const body = document.body;
const html = document.documentElement;
const docHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight,  html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
const windowBottom = windowHeight + window.pageYOffset;
if (windowBottom >= docHeight) {

  this.setState({
    message:'bottom reached'
  });
} else {
  this.setState({
    message:'not at bottom'
  });
}
}
}
```

***How to a particular value to parent component return if bottom reached message state.?***

Answer (score 1):

You want to change a parent component on event in child component(ScrollDetector)?

If so pass the callback function, that will update parent component, as a prop.

Let's say you want to change the state of parent component based on scroll. You would have something like this.

```
<ScrollDetector checkIfBottomReached={this.checkIfBottomReached} />
```

while the implementation of function would be

```
isBottomReached() {
    this.setState({ isBottomReached: true });
}
```

or simply pass it shorthanded

```
<ScrollDetector checkIfBottomReached={() => this.setState({ isBottomReached: true })} />
```

and inside ScrollDetector component you would call this function when you reach the bottom, just by calling `this.props.checkIfBottomReached()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use and [event handler / callback function](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) and send a prop from parent to child so it notifies when bottom has been reached:

```
class ScrollDetector extendsReactComponent {
  handleScroll() {
    ...
    if (windowBottom >= docHeight) {
      this.props.onBottomReached()
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

and from your parent component:

```
class YourParent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ScrollDetector
          onBottomReached={() => console.log('bottom reached!') }
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```